# Is there a way to fetchLess? Apollo Pagination

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pagination, apollo

**Is there a way to fetch less results using offsetLimitPagination inside TypePolicies?** For example, when I click "Show more", 4 more results would appear, and now the button will change into "Show less", and when it is clicked, it will display 4 "less" results.

I tried something like this:

```
fetchMore({
      variables: { offset: page * 4 - 4 }, //Previous page's worth of posts
})
```

And of course, it won't display less because it will just continue merging.

Is there something that I need to change in my FieldPolicies inside
offsetLimitPagination()? I searched around but I haven't
found a way to "fetch less".